# Cannot select my Android module for unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I'm developing an Android module and this is the second time that something weird is happening to the project. Please see the following screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdoom.png

1. The project consists of 3 parts - 1 a module (pointed by 1) and 2 apps
2. I'm trying to select that module so that I can run unit tests on it and as you can see (with arrow number 2), it does not appear on the list of available modules.

Some additional notes:

- I've been working on this module for a few months now and I've executed plenty of tests on it until now
- The problem occurred after I tried setting up aar signing (which than I dropped as i realized that is pointless in my case)
- When I tried to execute my existing unit tests, I got an "Empty test suite” error
- I did not change any settigns in the build.gradle file to trigger this issue. the current configuration was working for months without any change
- The last time this happen, the only was out was to pull the entire code base from the repo into a different folder. Weirdly, reverting/deleting the Android project folder was not enough and Android Studio still could not see the module

Thanks.

Comment: First of all try cleaning the Android Studio cache, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: I tried it and it still does't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What ended up causing the problem was that the build variant was set to Release. When I switched back to Debug all my unit tests OK again.